# jquery post form data and MVC model binder

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to post a knockoutjs view model via jquery post

```
var $form = $('#barcodeTemplate form');
var data = ko.toJS(vm.Template);

$.post($form.attr('action'), data);
```

The view model contains some simple properties and an array with complex 
objects. This is the JS object:

```
data: Object
Description: "abcde"
Fields: Array[2]
  0: Object
    Id: 1
    Length: 5
    Start: 2
    Type: "Code"
  1: Object
    Id: 2
    Length: 4
    Start: 8
    Type: "Price"
  length: 2
Flag: "02"
Id: 1
Type: "Embedded"
```

When serialised as form data it looks like this:

```
Id:1
Type: "Embedded"
Description: "abcde"
Fields[0][Type]:"Code"
Fields[0][Start]:2
Fields[0][Length]:5
Fields[1][Type]:"Price"
Fields[1][Start]:8
Fields[1][Length]:4
```

On the controller side the base properties deserialise correctly (e.g. Id, Type) and the array has two elements, however on both of these all properties (Type, Start, etc.) are 0.

I suspect it is because the form elements use the square bracket notation on the array properties, instead of dot notation, like

Fields[0].Type

Would this be correct? If so, how can I change this behaviour so the MVC model binder can successfully decode the form data?

Note I also tried using ko.utils.postJson, but this was even worse - the array was completely empty.

Comment: Can you try posting it using  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'?

Comment: Can you try checking if the values are in your FormCollection?

Comment: Please update your question to include a repro: either replace `ko.toJS(vm.Template)` with fake data, or include a representative `vm.Template` in your code.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. You should use a Web API Controller that works like a charm to send and receive JSON data. Once you're in JavaScript sending JSON by AJAX is super-easy. You can make JSON work with an MVC controller, but it can give you some headaches (depending on the MVC version). You can google for how to do so. With Web API it works like a charm out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various suggestions but in the end gave up and just decided to do a normal form post, no ajax stuff. It meant setting up correct name attributes on the form elements knockout was managing but it works.